# Finding Files using regex

Tags: shell

I have some files inside a directory and the pattern of the filename is : "CUST_YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.csv" . I'm using the below command to find out only those files but it's returning nothing .

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -regex '.*CUST.*_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\.csv.*' -print
```

Comment: I don't think you need the `.*` if CUST_ is actually how your file starts

Comment: It is working fine for me on `find (GNU findutils) 4.6.0`

Comment: It's working for me too, version 4.4.2

Comment: Are the filenames case-sensitive? In that case you should use `-iregex` option. One more thing on find utils (man page says): The regular expressions understood by find are by default Emacs Regular Expressions, but this can be changed with the -regextype option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

`find . -maxdepth 1 -regex '\.\/CUST_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\.csv' -print`

In case, one is searching on a given path, try

`find ~/ -maxdepth 1 -regex '\/\w.*CUST_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\.csv' -print`

In case one wishes to validate the `date_time`, one can try the following `awk` script.

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f
{
  i = 1
  # Let's split the datetime into Year, Month, Day, Hour, Minute and Second.
  # We can validate each value separately.

  match($0, /\.\/(CUST_)([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})/, arr);

  if (arr[2] <= "1900" ||  arr[2] >= "2099")
    i = 0

  if (arr[3] < "1" && arr[3] > "12")
    i = 0

  if (arr[4] < "1" && arr[4] > "31")
    i = 0
    #print "Invalid day"

  if (arr[5] > "23")
    i = 0
    #print "Invalid hour"

  if (arr[6] > "59")
    i = 0
    #print "Invalid minute"

  if (arr[7] > "59")
    i = 0
    #print "Invalid second"

  if (i == "1")
    print $0

}
```

**Usage:** `find . -maxdepth 1 -regex '\.\/CUST_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\.csv' -print | ./validate`

The above script is deliberately kept very verbose and can be refactored to be more efficient.

Comment: and If I want to validate that filename is with proper datetime or not ?

Comment: It can be done. Need to think. I presume you are using some flavour of *NIX?

Comment: I meant it can be done. Need to give some serious thought. Checking out

Comment: Are you using Linux?

Comment: Yes . I'm using linux .

Comment: Could you try the script?

Comment: What is $0 in the match function ?

Comment: $0 is the argument given to `awk` script. In this case, it is filename.

Comment: I didn't use this script cause I've more things to validate but I used your logic , logic is proper  . I'll upload that after some time . In your previous script it was finding the files from current directory , But If I give a path it was showing error cause at that case path name should be concatenate  with the regex . I was trying it but it is not happening . Can you please help me out ?

Comment: Updated the answer. Check out.